# How can I control for unobserved heterogeneity with cross-sectional data?

Tags: regression, spss, stata, cross-section, heterogeneity

I want to run a cross sectional regression for 700 firms in the US to test the impact of working capital on profitability. I specifically want to limit my analysis to the 2008 financial crisis and want to see how certain financial ratios impacted firms in 2008. I understand that I can take a few years (2008, 2009, 2010) and run a fixed effects model, therefore accounting for unobserved heterogeneity, however I specifically want to run a regression spanning 700 firms in one time period. Does anyone know how I can account for firm-varying unobservable heterogeneity since the firms span various sectors and have very different working environments? specifically, if there is a type of regression that accounts for this? I am working on SPSS and Stata.

Thanks.

Comment: Weighted least squares is one time-honored method for mitigating heterogeneity, the *whitening* transformation might be another.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at a cross-sectional regression with non-time related subgroups, say, linear

$$y_{is} = \mathbf x_{si}'\beta + \mathbf z_{si} + \mathbf g_s+ v_{si}$$

where $s$ indicates the subgroup (different industry for example)

and your individual $z$ variables are not observable as data.

Group-wise heterogeneity (different industries, geographical) could be dealt with by including indicator functions to represent $\mathbf g$.

But you cannot account for *individual*, observation-per-observation heterogeneity with a cross sectional sample *and* using least-squares estimation.

You could look for an indirect approach by using the [two-tier stochastic frontier model](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-47106-4_8), that requires maximum likelihood estimation, and it can provide measures of unobservable variables at the individual firm level.

Comment: Thanks Alecos. So in relation to the equation you presented, "g" would consist of dummy variables to represent the sectors?

Comment: @MazenMourad Yes.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: Please see request for information about CV.SE work [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/).